# Hive NVL does not work with Date type of the column - NullpointerException

Tags: java, hadoop, nullpointerexception, hive

I am using MapR Hive distribution over HDFS and facing below issue.
If for a table the column type is 'Date' type, then the [NVL](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-ConditionalFunctions) function does not work. The same is working for other datatype.

It simply throws

```
NullpointerException:Null
```

Even explain function is throwing same exception.

Kindly help here. Is it a bug in Hive distribution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem myself with a workaround:

For Date type, you could use hive `COALESCE` function as below:

```
COALESCE(nt.assess_dt, cast('9999-01-01' as date))
```

The above answer can be explain as:

- Find `nt.assess_dt` (which is a `date` type column); if it is `null` get the next value in the `COALESCE` function; which is a non-null value in above example and hence will be returned back.

Please note that it is a little different than NVL, where the value returned by the `COALESCE` needs to be of same type. Hence a blank `''` can not be returned by `COALESCE` in the above example.

Due to this, I have used a very large date value `9999-01-01` to represent a `null` value and distinguish between a genuine date value. In case your date column can have indeed this large value as a valid value, you should think of some other valid date value to represent a `null` date.

Get more about this and other alternative [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-ConditionalFunctions)

Comment: It is possible to do it as `case date_column when null then '' else cast(date_column as string) end`.

Answer (score 0):

One can also use the originally requested NVL, as in

```
NVL(nt.assess_dt, cast('9999-01-01' as date))
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted NVL's second parameter as CURRENT_DATE, but NVL throws NullpointerException like original question.

So I found an answer for this case :

```
NVL(dt, from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(), 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem too. And I found the input params didn't match. Like nvl(create_date,'1990-01-01'), create_date is DATE tyep, '1990-01-01' is String type, so the NPE throw. You can solve this problem like this:

```
nvl(create_date,cast('1990-01-01' as date))
```