# How to handle Null value for Date type in Hive

Tags: hive

I am trying handling NULL value for date type in hive 0.13, I keep on getting nullpointer exception error, below is my code, I used coalesce as well, same issue

```
NVL(NT_dt, to_date('9999-12-01')) as exp_dt
```

Comment: Can you please share the stacktrace? It will help to debug the issue.

Comment: Check this : [hive-nvl-does-not-work-with-date-type-of-the-column-nullpointerexception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32269671/hive-nvl-does-not-work-with-date-type-of-the-column-nullpointerexception)

Comment: I used coalesce, tried using case as well, same issue nullpointerexception,

Comment: **RTFM** -- function `to_date()` is not a general-purpose conversion utility from String tto Date *(this is not bloody Oracle)*. Since you have an ISO date, just use `cast('9999-12-01' as date)`.

Comment: And `nvl()` also smells like a lousy port of an Oracle thing. What about a verbose-but-explicit `case when NT_DT is not null then NT_DT else cast('9999-12-01' as date) end`?